# How can I build a front end for querying a Redshift database (hopefully with Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

So I have a Redshift database with enough tables that it feels worth my time to build a front end to make querying it a little bit easier than just typing in SQL commands.

Ideally, I'd be able to do this by connecting the database to a Rails app (because I have a bit of experience with Rails). I'm not sure how I'd connect a remote Redshift database to a local Rails application though, or how to make activerecord work with redshift.

Does anyone have any suggestions/resources to help me get started? I'm open to other options to connect the Redshift database to a front end if there are pre-made options easier than Rails.

Comment: see below, just had to do the same thing for my own project

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#app/models/data_warehouse.rb
class DataWarehouse < ActiveRecord::Base                      
  establish_connection "redshift_staging"
  #or, if you want to have a db per environment
  #establish_connection "redshift_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

Note that we are connecting on 5439, not the default 5432 so I specify the port
Also, I specify a schema, beta, which is what we use for our unstable aggregates, you could either have a different db per environment as mentioned above, or use various schemas and include them in the search path for ActiveRecord

```
#config/database.yml
redshift_staging:                                                          
  adapter: postgresql                                                      
  encoding: utf8                                                           
  database: db03                                                         
  port: 5439                                                               
  pool: 5                                                                  
  schema_search_path: 'beta'                                                                                          
  username: admin                                                        
  password: supersecretpassword                                               
  host: db03.myremotehost.us  #your remote host here, might be an aws url from Redshift admin console
```

###OPTION 2, a direct PG Connection

```
  class DataWarehouse < ActiveRecord::Base                      

    attr_accessor :conn                                                       

    def initialize                                                            
      @conn = PG.connect(                                                     
       database: 'db03',                                                   
       port: 5439,                                                           
       pool: 5,                                                              
       schema_search_path: 'beta',                                           
       username: 'admin',                                                  
       password: 'supersecretpassword',                                         
       host: 'db03.myremotehost.us'                                               
      )                                                                       
    end    
  end


[DEV] main:0> redshift = DataWarehouse
E, [2014-07-17T11:09:17.758957 #44535] ERROR -- : PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice" : SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice" : SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'>
```

**UPDATE:**

#### I ended up going with option 1, but using this adapter for now for multiple reasons:

https://github.com/fiksu/activerecord-redshift-adapter

Reason 1: ActiveRecord postgresql adapter sets client_min_messages
Reason 2: adapter also attempts to set Time Zone, which redshift doesn't allow (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)
Reason 3: Even if you change the code in ActiveRecord for the first two errors, you run into additional errors that complain that Redshift is using Postgresql 8.0, at that point I moved on to the adapter, will revisit and update if I find something better later.

#### I renamed my table to base_aggregate_redshift_tests (notice plural) so ActiveRecord was easily able to connect, if you can't change your table names in redshift use the set_table method I have commented out below

```
#Gemfile:
gem 'activerecord4-redshift-adapter', github: 'aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter'
```

## Option 1

```
#config/database.yml
redshift_staging:                                                                                                             
  adapter: redshift                                                                                                           
  encoding: utf8                                                                                                              
  database: db03                                                                                                           
  port: 5439                                                                                                                  
  pool: 5                                                                                                                     
  username: admin                                                                                                
  password: supersecretpassword                                                                                                  
  host: db03.myremotehost.us                                                                                                       
  timeout: 5000   

#app/models/base_aggregates_redshift_test.rb
#Model named to match my tables in Redshift, if you want you can set_table like I have commented out below

class BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "redshift_staging"
  self.table_name = "beta.base_aggregates_v2"
end
```

## in console using self.table_name -- notice it queries the right table, so you can name your models whatever you want

```
[DEV] main:0> redshift = BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest.first                                                                    
D, [2014-07-17T15:31:58.678103 #43776] DEBUG -- :   BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest Load (45.6ms)  SELECT "beta"."base_aggregates_v2".* FROM "beta"."base_aggregates_v2" LIMIT 1
```

## Option 2

```
#app/models/base_aggregates_redshift_test.rb
class BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table "beta.base_aggregates_v2"

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'redshift',
    encoding: 'utf8',
    database: 'staging',
    port: '5439',
    pool: '5',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'supersecretpassword',
    search_schema: 'beta',
    host: 'db03.myremotehost.us',
    timeout: '5000'
  )

end

#in console, abbreviated example of first record, now it's using the new name for my redshift table, just assuming I've got the record at base_aggregates_redshift_tests because I didn't set the table_name

[DEV] main:0> redshift = BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest.first
D, [2014-07-17T15:09:39.388918 #11537] DEBUG -- :   BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest Load (45.3ms)  SELECT "base_aggregates_redshift_tests".* FROM "base_aggregates_redshift_tests" LIMIT 1
#<BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest:0x007fd8c4a12580> {
                                                :truncated_month => Thu, 31 Jan 2013 19:00:00 EST -05:00,
                                                :dma => "Cityville",
                                                :group_id => 9712338,
                                                :dma_id => 9999 
                                                }
```

Good luck @johncorser!

Comment: Nice. Worked well with this gist I found, which turns a URI in to a database.yml. Copied almost exactly, changed adapter to `redshift`: https://gist.github.com/mptre/1654167

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial helps you setup a rails app with a redshift adapter:

https://www.credible.com/code/setting-up-a-data-warehouse-with-aws-redshift-and-ruby/

In a nutshell:

Clone the [sample app](https://github.com/tuesy/redshift-ruby-tutorial):

```
git clone git@github.com:tuesy/redshift-ruby-tutorial.git
cd redshift-ruby-tutorial
```

Setup ENV Variables via `~/.bashrc` (or [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)):

```
export REDSHIFT_HOST=redshift-ruby-tutorial.ccmj2nxbsay7.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
export REDSHIFT_PORT=5439
export REDSHIFT_USER=deploy
export REDSHIFT_PASSWORD=<your password here>
export REDSHIFT_DATABASE=analytics
export REDSHIFT_BUCKET=redshift-ruby-tutorial
```

Use the [gem `activerecord4-redshift-adapter`](https://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter), in Gemfile:

```
'activerecord4-redshift-adapter', '~> 0.2.0' # For Rails 4.2
'activerecord4-redshift-adapter', '~> 0.1.1' # For Rails 4.1
```

Then you can query into redshift like you would with a normal AR model:

```
bundle exec rails c
RedshiftUser.count
```

(Disclosure: I havn't yet given this method a try, but I may soon)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider http://www.looker.com/. It's a frontend for exploring your DB, allowing easily savable queries and a GUI that the business guys can also use.